# Parsing error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react'

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, eslint, babel-loader, eslintrc

I have a React project. In the first line in every .js file where I import React, I am getting this error: `Parsing error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react'`.

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "admin",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "author": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=14.15 <15",
        "npm": "~6"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build-config:local": "CONFIG_ENV=local npm run build-config",
        "build-config:dev": "CONFIG_ENV=dev npm run build-config",
        "build-config:staging": "CONFIG_ENV=staging npm run build-config",
        "build-config:prod": "CONFIG_ENV=prod npm run build-config",
        "build-config": "buildconfig --env $CONFIG_ENV",
        "build": "npm run build-config && webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --mode production",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.dev.js --mode development"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.7",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.15",
        "axios": "^0.21.4",
        "axios-progress-bar": "^1.2.0",
        "classnames": "^2.3.1",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "copy-text-to-clipboard": "^3.0.1",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",
        "css-loader": "^6.3.0",
        "date-fns": "1.30.1",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
        "humanize-string": "^2.1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "loglevel": "^1.7.1",
        "rc-checkbox": "^2.1.7",
        "rc-collapse": "^3.1.2",
        "rc-switch": "^3.2.2",
        "react": "^16.3.0",
        "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.3",
        "react-bootstrap-table2-editor": "^1.4.0",
        "react-bootstrap-table2-filter": "^1.3.3",
        "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.1.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-json-tree": "^0.15.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
        "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.4.4",
        "sass": "^1.42.1",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "serialize-error": "^8.1.0",
        "single-config": "^2.0.1",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.0",
        "svg-react-loader": "^0.4.6",
        "webpack": "^5.53.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "stylelint": "^13.13.0",
        "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.2",
        "stylelint-config-recommended": "^5.0.0",
        "stylelint-order": "^4.1.0",
        "stylelint-prettier": "1.2.0",
        "stylelint-scss": "3.19.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.2.1"
    }
}
```

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
    "plugins": ["react", "import", "jsx-a11y", "prettier"],
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "requireConfigFile": false,
        "babelOptions": {
            "presets": ["@babel/react"]
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect"
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": "error",
        "consistent-return": "warn",
        "no-console": "warn",
        "eqeqeq": "error",
        "no-alert": "error",
        "no-caller": "error",
        "no-constructor-return": "error",
        "no-else-return": "error",
        "no-eq-null": "error",
        "no-eval": "error",
        "no-extend-native": "error",
        "no-extra-bind": "error",
        "no-extra-label": "error",
        "no-floating-decimal": "error",
        "no-implicit-globals": "error",
        "no-implied-eval": "error",
        "no-iterator": "error",
        "no-lone-blocks": "error",
        "no-loop-func": "error",
        "no-multi-spaces": "error",
        "no-multi-str": "error",
        "no-new-func": "error",
        "no-new-wrappers": "error",
        "no-octal-escape": "error",
        "no-proto": "error",
        "no-return-assign": "error",
        "no-return-await": "error",
        "no-script-url": "error",
        "no-self-compare": "error",
        "no-sequences": "error",
        "no-throw-literal": "error",
        "no-unmodified-loop-condition": "error",
        "no-unused-expressions": "error",
        "no-useless-call": "error",
        "no-useless-concat": "error",
        "no-useless-return": "error",
        "require-await": "error",
        "arrow-body-style": ["error", "as-needed"],
        "arrow-spacing": ["error", { "before": true, "after": true }],
        "no-duplicate-imports": "error",
        "no-useless-constructor": "error",
        "no-useless-rename": "error",
        "no-var": "error",
        "no-useless-computed-key": "error",
        "prefer-arrow-callback": "error",
        "prefer-const": "error",
        "prefer-spread": "error",
        "prefer-template": "error",
        "rest-spread-spacing": "error",
        "symbol-description": "error",
        "comma-spacing": ["error", { "before": false, "after": true }],
        "key-spacing": "error",
        "keyword-spacing": "error",
        "max-len": ["error", { "code": 160 }],
        "linebreak-style": "error",
        "lines-between-class-members": "error",
        "new-cap": "error",
        "no-multi-assign": "error",
        "no-negated-condition": "warn",
        "no-nested-ternary": "error",
        "no-new-object": "error",
        "no-trailing-spaces": "error",
        "prefer-object-spread": "error",

        "react/prop-types": "off",
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".tsx"] }],

        "react/sort-comp": [
            "error",
            {
                "order": ["static-variables", "static-methods", "lifecycle", "everything-else", "/^is.+$/", "/^on.+$/", "/^render.+$/", "render"],
                "groups": {
                    "lifecycle": [
                        "displayName",
                        "propTypes",
                        "contextTypes",
                        "childContextTypes",
                        "mixins",
                        "statics",
                        "defaultProps",
                        "state",
                        "instance-variables",
                        "constructor",
                        "getDefaultProps",
                        "getInitialState",
                        "getChildContext",
                        "getDerivedStateFromProps",
                        "componentWillMount",
                        "UNSAFE_componentWillMount",
                        "componentDidMount",
                        "componentWillReceiveProps",
                        "UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps",
                        "shouldComponentUpdate",
                        "componentWillUpdate",
                        "UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate",
                        "getSnapshotBeforeUpdate",
                        "componentDidUpdate",
                        "componentDidCatch",
                        "componentWillUnmount"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],

        "import/no-unresolved": "off",
        "import/order": [
            "error",
            {
                "pathGroups": [
                    {
                        "pattern": "*.scss",
                        "group": "object",
                        "patternOptions": { "matchBase": true },
                        "position": "after"
                    },
                    {
                        "pattern": "*.svg",
                        "group": "object",
                        "patternOptions": { "matchBase": true },
                        "position": "after"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

**webpack.config.dev.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = () => ({
    devServer: {
        port: 8084,
        historyApiFallback: true, // serves index.html for all routes to avoid 404
        hot: true
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    stats: 'minimal',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[fullhash].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')],
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sassOptions: {
                                quietDeps: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath: 'images/',
                    useRelativePath: false
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            favicon: './src/assets/favicon/favicon-32x32.png'
        })
    ]
});
```

Comment: Try `npm add @babel/runtime` [source](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7183#issuecomment-500063595)

Comment: @Taxel I installed `@babel/runtime`, but it didn't help. I tried to remove `node_modules`, `package-lock.json` and install packages again, but nothing changed.

Comment: In case you are using VScode I suspect  this could be due to vscode related issues, can you try restarting vscode. Or try starting from scratch in a different directory with just these config files first and then doing `npm i` to verify if it works. I tried using your config files and it is working fine.

Comment: @AkleshSakunia that's strange. I am sure I restarted vscode and tried to reinstall packages, but I will try it out to run it in a different directory.

Comment: Try commenting `"presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]`, running the project and un-comment it again

Comment: @AkleshSakunia you are right. I am using cloud9 enviroment where is the project and connect through VS Code and its plugin Remote Explorer. When I tried this locally, I didn't get any errors.

Comment: @Matt glad I was able to suggest something meaningful

Answer (score 22):

If this appears in VSCode with the fullstack approach (front and back as subfolders within your workspace), adjust eslint extensions configurations for your current workspace in `.vscode/settings.json` as following:

```
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [
    "./back",
    "./front"
  ]
```

That solved this issue in my case.

Comment: worked for me! thanks

Answer (score 12):

Maybe it'll help someone, I just had a simillar problem which I solved.

I happened to have VSCode opened in a fullstack project where front and back were sepparate folders. When I opened VSCode **only** in the front folder this error faded away.

I guess a solution would be to make a shared node_modules folder or setup a workspace from front and back folders, I went with the 2nd option.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan! I have a similar folder setup, and opening folders separately fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you! Would have taken me forever to figure that out.

Comment: This worked for me as well but seems like a band-aid solution. Would love it if the problem was resolved with both folders opened.

Comment: I do have both folders open. I use the workspace vscode feature to open 2 folders separately. It is indeed a hacky way to solve this issue, I hope you can respond here if you find a better fix.

Answer (score 5):

Try installing @babel/preset-react explicitly, since someone had told that is isn’t installed by default:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react
```

Also, in the **eslint.json** file, you have referred to `@babel/react` instead of `@babel/preset-react` under babelOptions.

Answer (score 2):

I have been having the same issue. I fixed the issue by removing the

```
> @babel/eslint-parser // from eslintrc.js to 
> babel/eslint-parser
```

I notice in package.json I have babel/eslint not @bable/eslint

Comment: `parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    requireConfigFile: false,
    sourceType: "module",
     allowImportExportEverywhere: true,
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    },
    babelOptions: {
      presets: ["@babel/preset-react"]
    }`

Answer (score 0):

After trying to figure this one out for a few hours, replacing `@babel/preset-react`  with `babel-preset-react-app` finally worked.

Here's my full package.json (where there might be some mix up between dependencies / dev-dependencies though)

```
{
  "name": "----",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.4",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.6.2",
    "immer": "^9.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "7.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0-next.47",
    "redux": "4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.7.4",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.19",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.19",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "*",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your **webpack.config.js** file

```
Encore
//...
.enableReactPreset()
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing this line from `.eslintrc` worked for me

```
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
```