# Parsing error: cannot find module '@babel/preset-react' when loading multiple projects into VSCode at once

Tags: visual-studio-code, babeljs, eslint, parsing-error

After updating from `babel-eslint` to `@babel/eslint-parser`, currently in VSCode (with multiple project folders all loaded at once, collectively in a parent folder that contains all projects),   we are receiving the same problem for every file in our react project:

[image]

Per this post - [Parsing error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69467016/parsing-error-cannot-find-module-babel-preset-react):

> Maybe it'll help someone, I just had a similar problem which I solved. I happened to have VSCode opened in a fullstack project where front and back were separate folders. When I opened VSCode only in the front folder this error faded away. I guess a solution would be to make a shared node_modules folder or setup a workspace from front and back folders, I went with the 2nd option.

Can confirm that our full-stack project (React frontend, Node backend) is in one directory, and that loading only the frontend directory in VS code resolves the issue. **However**, we have a strong preference for loading multiple projects at once - a single high-level `github-projects` directory of ours, that contains multiple different projects, into VSCode. We are seeking a solution that truly resolves the issue, rather than side-stepping the issue by only loading a single project folder with our React app.

Is there anyway to resolve this issue while still loading multiple projects into VSCode? I have attempted to install `@babel/eslint-parser` globally however it did not resolve the issue.

**Edit:** our .babelrc file inside the react project. Presets commented out as including them / uncommenting it did not resolve the issue.

```
{
    "env": {
        "production": {
            "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
            // "presets": [
            //     "@babel/preset-react"
            // ]
        }
    }
}
```

We've tried updating `ecmaVersion` to 2022 in both .eslistrc files, with no luck. We've also tried installing `@babel/eslint-parser` in both FE and BE projects, with no luck resolving issue.

.eslintrc in `parent-dir/client` for react app:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "nconf": true
  },
  // "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2022,
    "requireConfigFile": false,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      ...
```

.eslintrc in `parent-dir/server` for node app:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "globals": {
        "nconf": true
    },
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    // "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "plugins": ["react"],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2022,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
        ...
```

Comment: Is your project opensource, or proprietary? Basically what I want to know is if there is a place it can be viewed publically, or is it behind closed doors, company type stuff?

Comment: You know, this is probably being caused by the way ESLint cascades when it resolves. I will try to reproduce it. One thing you could try is explicitly declaring the root ESLint configuration. By setting `root: true` in your eslintrc file. It might be a long shot, but Its worth trying, it helps ESLint know not to look in any parent folders for the root config.

Comment: Well authored question by the way

Comment: Thank you. It is a private project. One of the answers in the questions I linked to - `If this appears in VSCode with the fullstack approach (front and back as subfolders within your workspace), adjust eslint extensions configrations for your workspace as following...` ended up working for me.

Comment: Oh great! Despite not being able to collect a self posted bounty, you should still write your own answer.